# get reference to spring bean from class in src/groovy

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I'm writing a Grails plugin that defines a Spring bean in the plugin descriptor

```
def doWithSpring = {
    myBean(MyBean)
}
```

I need to get a reference to this bean from another class in the plugin.

```
class Something {

  def doIt() {
    // I need to get a reference to myBean here. Is this the best way?
    MyBean myBean = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('myBean')
  }
}
```

`Something` is a class defined in `src/groovy` within the same plugin as the bean, but `Something` is not itself a spring bean. In Grails 1.3.7 is there a better way of achieving this than that shown above? I'm looking for a better way because I know the *Holder classes are deprecated in Grails 2.0

Comment: From where are you going to be creating an instance of the Something class?

Answer (score 1):

In Grails 2.x exists the [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.1/api/grails/util/Holders.html) utility class to get the `grailsApplication` and the `applicationContext`.

In 1.3.7 I think the option is create your own holder, as described [here](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017).